# Fluent NHibernate and friend relationship

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I need to model a friend relationship with Fluent NHibernate. My company model has a `List<Company> Related` with related companies. Relations between companies are modeled in my database in a table, `related` which looks like this:

`customer_id | related_id`

Both columns is a foreign key to the PK in my `customers` table.

The problem is that relations are only saved once for each pair (do you call it bi-directional?).

*I'm able to change the table structure if it's easier to solve in another way.*

I need to map Fluent NHibernate so that when i do `customer.Related()`, it generates a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM companies LEFT JOIN related ON customer_id = id OR related_id = id
```

I've tried to map this in a number of different ways, the closest i've tried is:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Related)
       .Inverse()
       .ParentKeyColumn("customer_id")
       .ChildKeyColumn("related_id")
       .Table("relations")
       .Cascade.All();
```

However, this (of course) only maps when customer_id matches.

How do I solve this?

Edit:
I think it's similar to [Fluent NHibernate: How to create one-to-many bidirectional mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310641/fluent-nhibernate-how-to-create-one-to-many-bidirectional-mapping), but it does not help me much.

Comment: @Michael, thanks for your answer. I already has .Inverse(). Or am I missunderstanding you?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve is already half way done. You've mapped 2 entities with a Many2Many relation already. I wouldn't touch mapping any further.

Instead I would query what I want thru that mapping. Something like this.

```
function GetRelated(long id){

   return Session.Query<Related>()
                 .Where(r=>r.Customer.Id == id || r.Related.Id == id)
                 .ToList(); 
}
```

A reccomendation tho, the mapped entity's name is Related and you have a related field that might sound confusing, so I'd suggest you to rename it into something else (if possible).

Hope it helps.